# Фиксированная шапка при скроле вниз

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, есть вот такая таблица http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/hQVeE/
Как сделать так чтобы при скроле вниз шапка оставалась на месте как здесь http://www.stalkron.com/ru/aisi/index.php , но при скроле вправо она скролилась вместе со всей таблицей, fixed не предлагать он не поможет так как вправо будит съезжать таблица от шапки. Буду благодарен, за помощь.

Comment: Разве это не тот же вопрос ?  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/205397/javascript-заголовок-таблицы-при-скроле-вверх-вниз-должен-оставаться-на-месте

Comment: вопрос тот, но ответ не полный, при скроле вправо, шапка остается на месте, а надо чтоб она двигалась вместе с таблицей и ячейки не съезжали.

Comment: Нашёл скрипт и приделал для своей таблицы вот что получилось http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/GSLf3/
но при полном скроле вправо шапка немного съезжает. как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл скрипт и приделал для своей таблицы вот что получилось http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/GSLf3/ но при полном скроле вправо шапка немного съезжает. как это исправить?